# Can't ping window vm from Centos vm. How can i fix this?

Tags: windows, centos, virtual-machine

I have added the window's vm ip address in /etc/hosts and similary placed hostname and ip address  under C//Windows/System32/etc/hosts folder but yet on pinging the packets is not receiving.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I can't to do comments that's why I writing here. Do you use cloud provider or other virtualization tool (virtualbox for exampele)?

If you don't have curl instal it use

```
sudo yum install curl
```

Try to use curl command and then look to the log file

```
curl google.com
```

And then look to the log file at log file. You can read here about [log file](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-log-files-location-and-how-do-i-view-logs-files/)

After that please check your mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for the help.Actually needed to disable the windows defender on windows vm. Ping is working now.

Answer (score 0):

needed to disable the windows defender on windows vm to enable communication.